# Unity Rotate object with PS4 controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity but I'm trying to rotate an object around the Y axis using controller input (right stick). So if the stick is pushed right, the object will rotate towards the right. Here is my code so far.

```
public class TurnBall : MonoBehaviour {

    PlayerControls controls;
    Vector2 aim;

    void Awake() {
        controls = new PlayerControls();
        controls.Gameplay.Aim.performed += ctx => aim = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        controls.Gameplay.Aim.canceled += ctx => aim = Vector2.zero;
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.Rotate(0, aim.x, 0, Space.World);
    }

    void onEnable() {
        controls.Gameplay.Enable();
    }

    void onDisable() {
        controls.Gameplay.Disable();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is your code doing right now and how is that different to what you want to happen?

Comment: Well that's the problem, nothing happens, I have created the input actions properly and everything bu tI just don't know what's wrong...